# Needing to clean a project after each run with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Build Automatically checked. However, after each run, I still need to clean the project I am using—otherwise, I will generally get an exception specifying "Error: Could not find or load main class mypackage.MyClass in module mymodule". Any ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right clicking on the class file and then selecting "Run as" > "1 Java Application" appears to have resolved this problem.

Comment: I plan on marking this answer as accepted in two days (when Stack Overflow allows).